# Need Help Understanding Segmentation Faults

Tags: c

I get what segfaults are and what causes them, my question is why is my pointer causing them? I'm trying to write a simple linked list that adds on nodes containing 5 and I get the segfault at temp->x = 5;. I thought malloc() should have allowed me access to the memory it needs?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
  int x;
  struct node *next;
};


void append(struct node *root){

   struct node *temp, *right;
   temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   temp->x = 5;
   right = (struct node *)root;

   while(right->next != NULL){
       right = right->next;
   }

   right->next = temp;
   right = temp;
}

int main(){

   struct node *root;

   root = NULL;


   int userInput;

   printf("Pick Operation: ");
   scanf("%d", &userInput);

   if(userInput == 1){
       append(root);
   }


}
```

Comment: `root = NULL;` .. `append(root);` as `append(NULL);` .. `right = (struct node *)root;` as `right = NULL;` .. `while(right->next != NULL){` as `while(NULL->next != NULL){`

Comment: cannot dereference a NULL pointer
`root = NULL;` `right=root;` 
dereferenced here  `while(right->next != NULL); `

Comment: As always, the standard warning: in `c`, don't cast the result of `malloc()`. And casting `root` to its own type is superfluous, obviously.

Comment: also `temp->x = 5;` --> `temp->x = 5;temp->next = NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not cause a segfault at `temp->x = 5;`.
It causes a segfault when you enter the `while` loop. `while(right->next != NULL)`

Since you initialize your `root` to null, so on the first call to append at the entrance of your `while` loop, you check `right->next` which is on a null object, and causes a segfault!!

Inserting an `if` condition at the beginning would solve your purpose, something like this ::

```
if(root == NULL) {
root = temp;
} else {
    while(right->next != NULL) {
       /*your loop*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here:

```
while(right->next != NULL){
   right = right->next;
}
```

You are trying to check "right->next" where "right" is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the line

```
printf("%d is okay\n",temp->x);
```

right after `temp->x = 5;`. Your program still crashes -- but only *after* it prints. Others have already pointed out the source of the error -- but it still doesn't hurt to know the basic trick of using judicious print statements to test your assumptions. Why did you think that line caused the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a  NULL pointer.  The root is `NULL` when you are calling `append`, and in the code

```
   ...
   right = (struct node *)root;
   while(right->next != NULL){
   ...
```

then in you are trying to dereference the null pointer when you are accessing `right-next`.

You need to step trough your code with a debugger.